# Can define a rule in GNU Make to unconditionally create a symlink at the start of every make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need to create a symlink to some of the code that make should compile. Can I get GNU Make to create the symlink unconditionally at the start of every make?

Background: I am running make in a test directory; the source to be tested is in a directory `../application/src` relative to where I run make. Make and GCC are fine with the source being outside the work directory, but one of the tools for reporting my coverage can't handle it. Hence the symlink, so everything is under the work directory.

What I have tried is to create a rule to make the link

```
appsrc: 
    ln -s ../application/src/ appsrc
```

And I made this a prerequisite of the rule to make .o files from the ../application/src files:

```
obj/%.o : appsrc/%.cpp appsrc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o ./obj/$(@F) -c $<
```

but it did not work. Not 100% sure why, I tried to understand the output of make -d but it's difficult -- I think it fails to find the `appsrc/%.cpp` file so does not get as far as running the appsrc rule.

So I added this rule:

```
appsrc/%: ../application/src/% appsrc
```

Now when make fails to find an application source file, say `appsrc/foo.cpp`, but can see `../application/src/foo.cpp`, it knows to run the appsrc rule.

And that worked -- **once**. But after that, it stopped working. Why? because now `appsrc/foo.cpp` is an "intermediate file", and there's no explicit rule to make *it*, so make went and deleted any such files! So now some of my source files are gone! Thank goodness for version control...

To prevent this I think I need to get rid of the `appsrc/%` rule. So can I replace it with something that will get run unconditionally? What would the syntax for that be in GNU Make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do it in a `$(shell ...)` function?

```
_dummy := $(shell ln -f -s ../application/src/ appsrc)
```

will run when the makefile is parsed.

Comment: Why? Only because I didn't know about them! Thanks!